# imagemin - code executes but nothing seems to happens

Tags: node.js, typescript, imagemin

I'm trying to compress an image in Node 14 with Typescript and using `imagemin`.

I took the examples I found online and run the code, but nothing seems to happen, it finishes without any errors.
The output is empty as well.

**imagemin version 7.0.1

node v14.15.4**

```
'use strict';
import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import imageminJpegtran from 'imagemin-jpegtran';

export async function compressImage(): Promise<void> {

const files = await imagemin(['../David.jpeg'], {
    destination: '../compressed-images',
    plugins: [
        imageminJpegtran(),
    ]
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(files, null, 1));
}
```

I build the code and then run it but the output is simply an empty array `[]`.
Also, nothing appears in the `../compressed-images` folder.

Please advise on how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to the path not being passed as an absolute path. This is the working code:

```
const pv = path.join(__dirname, '../../David.jpeg');

const files = await imagemin([pv], {
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../compressed-images'),
    plugins: [
        imageminMozjpeg({quality: 50})
    ]
});
```